# Django: Reverse for 'thread' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<forum_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<thread_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have tried to use two primary key at urls.py path but when I am using that  in template I cannot access that second primary key.

URL example: `forum/1/2`

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:forum_id>/<int:thread_id>/', views.thread, name='thread'),
```

**views.py**

```
def forum(request,forum_id):
    forums = get_object_or_404(ForumModel, id=forum_id)
    threads = ThreadModel.objects.filter(forum=forums)
    context={'forums':forums,'threads':threads}
    return render(request,'forumdetail.html',context)

def thread(request, thread_id):
    thread = get_object_or_404(ThreadModel, id=thread_id)
    posts = PostModel.objects.filter(thread=thread)
    context={'thread':thread,'posts':posts}
    return render(request,'threaddetail.html',context)
```

**template**

```
<ul>
{% for thready in threads %}

<li>{{ thready.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33714615/edit) your question and improve formatting, you can find more information at [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Where is an attempt to access "second primary key in a template"? Or any pk. Where is url reversion attempt which gives the error? Please show related code.